# Obtain the number of students of a teacher

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder, laravel-relations

- `teacher` has a **one-to-many** relationship with the `course`.
- `course` **belongs to one** `teacher`.
- `student` **can participate in several** `courses`.
- `course` **can include several** `students`.

According to Laravel standards, I also wrote the interface and relation table in the model.

**Now I want to get the number of students of a teacher** in `TeachersController` And if possible, get a list of his students.

### Teacher Model

```php
public function course()
{
    return $this->hasMany(course::class);
}
```

### Course Model

```php
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Teacher::class);
}

public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class)
        ->withPivot('start_date', 'cancel_date', 'status');
}
```

### Student Model

```php
public function courses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(course::class)
        ->withPivot('status', 'start_date', 'cancel_date');
}
```

---

I tried to get the list and number of students through the course model defined in the teacher relation to the student model defined in the course model. But Laravel makes a mistake.

```php
public function show(Teacher $teacher)
{
    $countStudent =  $teacher->course()->get()->students();
    dd($countStudent);
}
```

Comment: ```public function show(Teacher $teacher)
    {$teacher_courses =  $teacher->course()->get();
        $sumCountOfStudent = 0;
        foreach ($teacher_courses as $course){
            $sumCountOfStudent += $course->students()->count();
        }
    }```

Comment: Have tried to make a `hasManyThrough` relatioship ? Also `course::class` should be written as`Course::class`

Comment: in `$teacher->course()->get()->students();` you are trying to apply the relationship `students();` on a **collection of course models** which is invalid

Comment: @medilies they can't use HasManyThrough because of the pivot table

Comment: ty for the info @lagbox I was searching how to do that and found this [post](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-has-many-through-pivot-elegantly-958dd096db) which was refereanced [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/using-hasmanythrough-through-a-pivot-table) too

Comment: @medilies
I tried to use this relationship. But it seems that interdependent models should have a one-to-many relationship. But there is a relationship between the student model and the course. That's why I got this error: 
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.course_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: @medilies $teacher->course()->get()->students();
its not work. give this error:  Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::students does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use hasManyThrough relationship [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

**Teacher.php**

```
 public function students() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Student::class, Course::class);
 }
```

in your controller

```
public function show(Teacher $teacher){

 $countStudent =  $teacher->students()->count();
    dd($countStudent);

}
```

Comment: give this error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.course_id' in 'on clause' . Because the relationship between course tables and students is not one to many. And does not have course_id.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function show(Teacher $teacher)
{
$countStudent =  $teacher->course()->students()->get();
        dd($countStudent);

}
```

You don't need to use get method in the middle

if you want to count, use `count()` instead of `get()`

Comment: this error gives:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::students()

Comment: `course` returns a relationship object which does not have a `students` method